# Invalid procedure call or argument when calling MergeArea

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sub that looks for empty cells and if cells are not empty it checks if the merged cells are empty. It calls `MergeArea` only after knowing that `MergeCells` is true. So I don't know why there is the error. This error depends on range - if there are no merged cells in the range it goes fine.

```
  Sub hide2()
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim wRange As Range
        Set wRange = Range("B23:P36")

        Dim k As Integer

        Dim cellFirst As Range

        For Each cell In wRange
            If IsEmpty(cell) Then
                k = k + 1
            ElseIf cell.MergeCells Then
                With cell.MergeArea
                    Set cellFirst = cell.MergeArea(Cells(1, 1))
                    If IsEmpty(cellFirst) Then
                        k = k + 1
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        Next
        MsgBox (k)
End Sub
```

Comment: you do not qualify a worksheet in your code. Are you sure the code is running on the sheet you desire it to run on. I ran the code and it worked well for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cell.MergeArea(Cells(1, 1))` will not give you the first cell in the MergeArea. Change the following:

```
With cell.MergeArea
    Set cellFirst = cell.MergeArea(Cells(1, 1))
    If IsEmpty(cellFirst) Then
        k = k + 1
    End If
End With
```

to:

```
With cell.MergeArea
    Set cellFirst = .Cells(1, 1)
    If IsEmpty(cellFirst) Then
        k = k + 1
    End If
End With
```

Or you could do away with `With`, `End With` and `Set`ting the range at all and just use

```
If IsEmpty(cell.MergeArea.Cells(1, 1)) Then
    k = k + 1
End If
```